# NHibernate group by named parameters doesn't work with repeated parameters

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, parameters

My query in HQL is basically:

```
select functionA(a, :paramA), functionB(b, :paramB), functionC(c, :paramC), sum(d)
from tableA
groupby by functionA(a, :paramA), functionB(b, :paramB), functionC(c, :paramC)
```

However this gets turned into SQL of

```
select functionA(a, @param0), functionB(b, @param1), functionC(c, @param2), sum(d)
from tableA
groupby by functionA(a, @param3), functionB(b, @param4), functionC(c, @param5)
```

Now obviously this is going to throw a `'blah' is invalid in the select list because....` error as the group by clause doesn't match the select clause. I'm about to change this to a string format so I can get on with some productive work but if anyone has the answer as to why NHibernate will not reuse the same named query input the 2 times it is used that would be much appreciated.

A similar question seems to have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065392/nhibernate-named-query-parameter-numbering-p1-p2-etc) with no real answer either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been solved in NHibernate 3.0.0.Alpha1. You can get it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/3.0.0Alpha1/NHibernate-3.0.0.Alpha1-bin.zip/download)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go. It's lucky this is on a personal project where I'm happy to use alpha software, wouldn't get away with that on a client project.

Comment: Don't let the name fool you - 3.0.0.Alpha1 is pretty stable, as it's based on the same codebase as 2.x and the project uses continuous integration.

Comment: Took a couple of gos to get all the right versions of DLLs but it is working perfectly. Cheers.